# hair dynamics with mesh cache object

Tags: hair

hello  I wish if I could birth hair on specific meshes on mesh cache object.
here the carpet object exported to obj(checked keep vert order) file and added modifier "mesh cache" and imported mdd file to apply baked cloth simulation,
it works fine until I check on Hair Dynamics,but It becomes strange when I check it on.
I appreciate for any advices.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

solved by changing parameter "Emit From"  from Faces to Verts.